# How to revert an old Git commit without impacting the later commits?

Tags: git, git-bash

I want to revert an older commit in a series of commits on a particular branch in GIT without impacting the later changes. i.e I want only the changes pushed as a part of a particular commit(earlier) to go, keeping the changes done later intact.

Also, How would the situation change if this branch has been merged with another branch later?

I can try this, but not sure if it would help.

```
git revert <CommitId>
```

Answer (score 1):

`git revert <commitXYZ>` will create a new commit on top of the current branch, containing the contrary of the changes introduced in `<commitXYZ>`. If the original (faulty) commit added a line, the revert commit will be the deletion of that line.

Let's say `B'` is the commit created when you do `git revert B` :

```
A --- B --- C --- D --- B'
```

Here A, B, C and D commits will stay untouched (yes, even `B`). The changes from B will appear no more at B' state, but commit B is still in the history.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do this today. You'll have to find the old commit and manually remove your changes with a code editor (I use Notepad++). Then label the commit as a revert (REVERT: ) and create a pull request.

Comment: Make sure that you pull in the most recent changes from your master branch.